# Macro that looks for a value in a cell & then paste a range in the column of that cell. EXCEL 2007

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a VBA code that automates a step I do everyday but I just can't.

In the column `B` i have some values that are different everyday, and the heading of the column `B` is the date `=Today()`.

The next columns headings are the days of the year..  so what I need is to copy the values of column `B`, look for the column that match with the day and then paste the values in that column.

Comment: To make sure I understand.  Cell B1 contains today's date.  Today B1 contains 3 January 2012 but three days ago it contained 31 December 2011.  Cells C1, D1, E1, and so on also contain dates.  You want a routine that finds cell X1 such that B1 and X1 contain the same date.  You then want Bn copied to Xn for every value of n.  Will column X be empty before this routine is run?  Do cells B1, C1 and so on contain Excel dates or are they strings?  If they are Excel dates do they contain times?  Is your problem that you do not know how to code such a routine or does your routine not work?

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `Sub` to accomplish this task

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim rDst As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim dat As Variant

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    ' Get the Source range
    Set rSrc = ws.Range([B2], ws.Columns(2).Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    dat = rSrc

    ' Find the Destination column and copy data
    Set rDst = ws.Range([C1], ws.Rows(1).Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    Set cl = rDst.Find(What:=[B1], _
      After:=rDst.Cells(1, 1), _
      LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
      SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If cl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Date Column for " & CStr([B2].Value) & " Not Found"
    Else
        Set rDst = cl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(dat, 1), 1)
        rDst = dat
    End If
End Sub
```

This code assumes the day headers are Formatted `DateSerial` numbers (same as the result of `=Today()`)
If this is not the case then the `Find(What:=[B2]` may need to change.

How it works:

1. Set a reference to the source data range
2. Copy source data to a variant array
3. Search for the date from cell `B2` in used range from `C1` to end of row
4. If not found report an error and end
5. Set up destination range
6. Copy source values into destination